# Premature end of script headers -- Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I am getting 500 internal server error after installing all gems.  Some people say it has to do with memory usage, but I am at 29%

This is my vhost

```
VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin examplea@example.com
      ServerName 0.0.0.0
      # ServerAlias
      DocumentRoot /var/www/sample_app/current/public
      ErrorLog /var/www/sample_app/error.log

          RailsEnv production
        <Directory "/var/www/sample_app/current/public">
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Does the code above need to be in a specific location in the vhost?  Is there something else I need to add?

Comment: Premature end of script headers

Comment: can you post the backtrace of the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had to delete the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default and create my own

Comment: I have the same problem can you be more detailed about this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure passenger is installed/enabled properly?

post your stack traces